# Why do applications look for "adwaita" themes?

Tags: gtk, theme

What's the deal with the Adwaita theme? Just about every application you can get on Linux are always looking to use the Adwaita theme, instead of just using the theme currently installed on the system.

more than often I see applications trying to load module engines that belong to Adwaita themes, and can cause issues for them when it can't find the module engine for it with GTK+ Warnings. Or is this just the theme engine trying to compensate for something when it's loading a theme? I don't really get what the deal is here with it, or why Adwaita specifically is needed for every application, or even depends on that specific theme set instead of loading with whatever theme a user has installed.

Moreso, is it possible to just simply disable adwaita from being used and loaded to suppress these kind of warnings that Adwaita produces? The warnings aren't very impacting on how applications run, but when you're busy trying to debug applications that crash unexpectedly, or refuse to run, it's pretty convoluted when you're scrolling through hundreds of hundreds of GTK Warnings by Adwaita.

Answer (score 3):

You might be a victim of the same confusion that I was. There is the Adwaita theme and then there is libAdwaita.so, which is part of the gnome-themes-standard. This shared library is the Adwaita theming engine, which the GTK applications use, regardless of what theme is used. The warnings are produced due to missing the gnome-themes-standard package. Try installing that to remove the warnings.

Comment: I have all the standard themes installed, yet they still persist, I also have the GTK2 murrine themes and such. So if they're all installed, I don't get how it can say it's missing when it's all there. Because I'm having issues starting Steam up because of these warnings.

Comment: gnome-themes-standard is not a theme. It is a theming engine. Check if you have that installed.

Comment: @ Munir - I have that installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary: It looks like the library provides a C-level interface to some useful Gnome/GTK GUI widgets.**

My package manager recently installed an update for this library (`libadwaita.x86_64`), so I followed the trail:

`$ dnf search adwaita`

```
libadwaita.x86_64 : Building blocks for modern GNOME applications
```

`$ dnf info libadwaita.x86_64`

```
Name         : libadwaita
Version      : 1.0.0
Release      : 0.6.alpha.4.fc35
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 327 k
Source       : libadwaita-1.0.0-0.6.alpha.4.fc35.src.rpm
Repository   : updates
Summary      : Building blocks for modern GNOME applications
URL          : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libadwaita
License      : LGPLv2+
Description  : Building blocks for modern GNOME applications.
```

And then after a bit of following links from the URL above, I got to this page:

https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/1.0.0.alpha.4/#classes

So it looks like the library provides a C-level interface to some useful Gnome/GTK GUI widgets.